# perl hash derived from array does not work as expected

Tags: perl, hash

I am having some trouble with using hash derived from array. It fails "exists" test for elements I know that are there. I wrote small test code to confirm this. Here it is:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

my @sieve = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19);
my %sieve_hash = @sieve;


foreach $prime (@sieve) {
    if (exists($sieve_hash{$prime})) {
    print "$prime exists!\n";
    } else {
    print "$prime DOES NOT exist.\n";
    }
}
```

Here is sample output:

```
2 exists!
3 DOES NOT exist.
5 exists!
7 DOES NOT exist.
11 exists!
13 DOES NOT exist.
17 exists!
19 DOES NOT exist.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When assigning to a hash, a list of alternating keys and values are expected. The following would solve your problem:

```
my %sieve_hash = map { $_ => 1 } @sieve;
```

With the above, a simple truth test (rather than an existence test) would suffice. But since you're using an existence test, you could save some memory by using the following to assign `undef` instead of `1`:

```
my %sieve_hash;
@sieve_hash{ @sieve } = ();
```

or

```
my %sieve_hash;
$sieve_hash{$_} = undef for @sieve;
```

I find a truth test much more elegant, though.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it very well.

Answer (score 1):

When you assign an array to a hash,  the even indexed elements, e.g. $sieve[0], $sieve[2] become the hash keys,  the odd numbered elements $sieve[1], $sieve[3], etc become the hash values.    You'll notice the pattern in your output where only every other element (the 0th, 2nd, 4th) "exists" as a key in the hash.

Use Data::Dumper to see what's going on:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Dumper;

my @sieve = (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19);
my %sieve_hash = @sieve;

print STDERR "Your array:\n";
print Dumper \@sieve;

print STDERR "Your hash:\n";
print Dumper \%sieve_hash;



Your array:
$VAR1 = [
          2,
          3,
          5,
          7,
          11,
          13,
          17,
          19
        ];
Your hash:
$VAR1 = {
          '11' => 13,
          '17' => 19,
          '2' => 3,
          '5' => 7
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
my %sieve_hash = @sieve;
```

It takes one every other element of the array as a key, the other elements as the value.

So your hash look the same as if it was constructed from:

```
my %sieve_hash = (
  2 => 3,
  5 => 7,
  ... and so on
);
```